# Access to samples of speech recognized signal in C#?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech, sfspeechrecognizer

How can i get acces to samples of signal that is processed by speechRecognitionEngine? [C#]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                                                    
    SpeechRecognitionEngine engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    Choices choices = new Choices();
    choices.Add(new string[] {"example", "example2"};

    GrammarBuilder grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
    grammarBuilder.Append(choices);
    Grammar grammar = new Grammar(grammarBuilder);

    engine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
    engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    engine.SpeechRecognized += engine_SpeechRecognized;
    ...
}

private void engine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

Basically my program recognizes speech well, but how can i get access to particular samples of the recognized signal? I know i can go with:

```
RecognizedAudio audio = e.Result.Audio;
```

but it doesn't give me the data i want. I want a vector of int's or something. Please help

Comment: How about converting your event args to a byte array?

Comment: thanks for the answer, sounds good. Do you have an idea maybe how would it look in code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the methods you should be using are WriteToAudioStream() and/or WriteToWavStream().

See the microsoft page for more details [WriteToAudioStream Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.recognizedaudio.writetoaudiostream(v=office.13).aspx)

something like this might get you started

```
        MemoryStream audioStream = new MemoryStream();
        e.Result.Audio.WriteToAudioStream(audioStream);
        //write to file
        FileStream file = new FileStream("d:\\file.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        audioStream.WriteTo(file);
        audioStream.Close();
        file.Close();
```